# C# Multithreading ASP .NET MVC 4 - Equivalent of System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, multithreading, asp.net-mvc-4

I study .NET and now i'm learning web developement with ASP .NET MVC 4.

I made a Task :

```
Task t = new Task(new Action(() =>
        {
            while (convert("suitandtie.mp4") != 1)
            {
                if (i == 4)
                {
                     // Here I want to access in mainthread property
                     // I need to change text for viewBag like :
                     // ViewBag.Message = "Convert failed";
                     // But I need a Dispatcher and invoke for accessing 
                     // the ViewBag of the mainthread

                    break;
                }
                i++;
            }
        }));
        t.Start();
```

In .Net Application, With System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher, it's possible to use it for call invoke.
I did that in my application :

```
 this.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
  {
      ContactBook.Add(Person("Mark", "232 521 424"));
  }));
```

When I added Mark in contact book, it added in the ContactBook of the mainthread, not of the thread created by Task.

Help please for accessing ViewBag.Message of the mainthread?

Comment: Considering the statelessness of MVC, I don't even know how you'd like to access the `ViewBag`'s property after the action ran to completion and view has been rendered. You either have to block the controller for processing and then show the message or make a client-side AJAX call (non-blocking).

Comment: Because this code is for converting a file video, and it can be long.
I want to load a new view. I don't want that the user wait the end of the process conversion, because it's one minute of waiting.
I would like to convert the file in a thread, and if the convert fail after 4 tries, I want to tell to the user that the conversion failed with the ViewBag.Message's property. 
You understand? If I don't do that in a thread, the view is blocked because of the controller...

Comment: And you just **can't** access the ViewBag from controller *after* the view has been rendered. It would make no sense, the view has been rendered and sent to the client, connection was closed, that's it. The fact that your worker thread is still running after you rendered the view doesn't make it any different. What you need is AJAX calls here...

Comment: Okay, I see...
Sorry, I'm a begginner in ASP .NET MVC.
There is a way to execute code after returning the view?
Or
Do you know a good tutorial about working ajax, in ASP .NET MVC 4 ?
With examples :s

Comment: Hello manonthemoon... welcome to the wonders of web development, let me introduce you to SignalR - http://signalr.net/

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to create that as a separated thread?

I am asking because unless the client is making aysn calls, there is no benefit in doing that, granted that you are not going to be doing many things at the same time and deferring the execution of the controller to some other service.

The easiest way if your you to pass in the current Thread to the ViewBag thought.

Comment: Because this code is for converting a file video, and it can be long. I want to load a new view. I don't want that the user wait the end of the process conversion, because it's one minute of waiting. I would like to convert the file in a thread, and if the convert fail after 4 tries, I want to tell to the user that the conversion failed with the ViewBag.Message's property. You understand? If I don't do that in a thread, the view is blocked because of the controller...

Comment: You can have a separated service doing that, let's say a windows services that your controller uses. You then have to have your client pooling another REST resource to see if the work is ready, but you can't do it the way you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

There is no mapping.  There is no means of interacting with the response because the response has [potentially] already been sent and the connection closed at that point in time.

If you start an asynchronous operation and don't have something in the request's context blocking on that operation then that async operation can't interact with the response at all.

The best that you'll be able to do is store the results of anything you generate in some external storage mechanism (such as a database) so that a future request from the server can get the information and send it to the client.

Comment: Okay, I will try to study the answer of Eilistraee.
To make an ajax system with SignalR. 
I hope it's not complicated

Comment: @manonthemoon Note that there's no inherent need to use AJAX.  It depends on how you want the user to end up seeing the results of the operation.  If they need to be notified as soon as the operation finishes you need AJAX, but if they don't need to see it until they load a new page then you don't need it at all, you can just have the async operation write the data to the database and have new page requests check it.

Answer (score 0):

The Viewbag (and any page state) is only available before the response was sent to the client. It's the way the classic webserver model works: The client request an URL, the server answers something (HTML, javascript, octet Stream...) If your operation is a few minutes long, you should consider using something slightly different.

Personnaly, I would load the initial page with a classical ASP.NET MVC action, then starting the long duration task through a subsequent javascript request.

To run the task, use something like [SignalR](http://www.signalR.net), which will enable you to perfom duplex communications between your client and your server. With SignalR, the server will be able to notify the client at the end of the task rather easily. And it's very easy to use in an ASP.NET MVC app.

Comment: Okay, I understand that it's an ajax system.
I'm gonna try to study this subject now, SignalR. I hope it's not complicated to learn it.
Thanks for tips

Comment: No, it's really easy to get started with SignalR :)

Comment: Just for installing I have problems lol.
I do exactly what says the documentation.
I don't know why the installation fails...

Comment: don't hesitate to start a question, and put the link here.